# Codenameone - AppStoreConnect Error - Missing Purpose String in Info.plist

Tags: codenameone

I've built an app with CN1 and busy submitting it to the Apple App Store. I uploaded the build via the Transporter app on my Mac but it was not showing up in App Store Connect. I then received an email from the App Connect "no-reply..." account saying they identified two issues with the build, something like...

> Dear Developer,
>
> We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app
> XXXXX. Please correct the following issues and then upload again.
>
> **ITMS-90683: Missing Purpose String in Info.plist** - Your app's code references
> one or more APIs that access sensitive user data. The app's Info.plist
> file should contain a **NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription** and **NSCameraUsageDescription** key(s), each with a
> user-facing purpose string explaining clearly and completely why your
> app needs the data. Starting spring 2019, all apps submitted to the
> App Store that access user data will be required to include a purpose
> string.If you're using external libraries or SDKs, they may reference
> APIs that require a purpose string. While your app might not use these
> APIs, a purpose string is still required. You can contact the
> developer of the library or SDK and request they release a version of
> their code that doesn't contain the APIs. Learn more blah, blah, url link...
>
> Best regards,
>
> The App Store Team

Thing is, I do not make use of either of those features (NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription,  NSCameraUsageDescription) in my app and have no idea on how to add it into the Application's "Info.plist". So...

1. Why are these features being added, are they part of the default CN1 build?
2. If so, how can I include the data they require, would this be added as build hints?

I have XCode 13 installed and have built the CN1 app with sources so could probably import the project and read up on how to do this but then would need to build it and deploy it with XCode which, imo, kinda defeats the purpose of using CN1 as a multi-platform tool (unless I'm combining my CN1 app with native code which this particular project of mine is not).

Comment: Is this a build made from sources or from our cloud servers?
Are you sure there's no usage of some API that might trigger the camera such as QR scanning or something like that?

Comment: Hi Shai. The build I uploaded to the App Store was taken from the CN1 cloud servers but when you mentioned QR scanning, I realised I had tried out the cn1-codecan lib a while back in my project but decided to rather use it in a later version of my app. However, I did not remove it from my libs folder which is what is triggering the error so thanks for that mention.

Not sure if this should be another question but should I have made use of the cn1-codescan lib, how would I add in those parameters? I had a look at the README on the project's Github page and do not see anything about that?

Comment: Just add a build hint `codename1.arg.ios.NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription` which includes your usage description as the argument. Do the same for `codename1.arg.ios.NSCameraUsageDescription`