# codenameone: ITMS-90683: Missing purpose string in Info.plist

Tags: ios, codenameone

When sending the generated app with codename one to the app store, through the transporter, it displays the following error:

ITMS-90683: Missing purpose string in Info.plist - Your app’s code references one or more APIs that access sensitive user data, or the app has one or more entitlements that permit such access. The Info.plist file for the “appname.app” bundle should contain a NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key with a user-facing purpose string explaining clearly and completely why your app needs the data. If you’re using external libraries or SDKs, they may reference APIs that require a purpose string. While your app might not use these APIs, a purpose string is still required. For details, visit: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/protecting_the_user_s_privacy/requesting_access_to_protected_resources.

ITMS-90683: Missing purpose string in Info.plist - Your app’s code references one or more APIs that access sensitive user data, or the app has one or more entitlements that permit such access. The Info.plist file for the “appname.app” bundle should contain a NSCameraUsageDescription key with a user-facing purpose string explaining clearly and completely why your app needs the data. If you’re using external libraries or SDKs, they may reference APIs that require a purpose string. While your app might not use these APIs, a purpose string is still required. For details, visit: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/protecting_the_user_s_privacy/requesting_access_to_protected_resources.

I was looking and found the following link that talks about the subject.

[[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69715715/codenameone-appstoreconnect-error-missing-purpose-string-in-info-plist]](https://stackoverflow.com)

The problem is that I can't get it right with the creation of the construction tip.
It would be something like this:
key: NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription
Value: codename1.arg.ios.NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription()

Key: NSCameraUsageDescription
Value: codename1.arg.ios.NSCameraUsageDescription()
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdgJU.png)

Thank you for your help!

Rui Alves

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a build hint such as `ios.NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription`. In the image you used `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription` (without the ios prefix).

The same is true for all `NS*UsageDescription` definitions.